# Plotting DataFrame in R ggplot shows an error for aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe:

dataframe(habSolyc05g052120.2):

```
Shab_ovul1 Shab_poll1 Shab_poll2 Shab_styl1  Shab_styl2 Shab_styl3

         0  0.6145496  0.3681263 0.04324981 0.002682159 0.04056765
```

I am just trying to do a simple point plot, before even adding in other species' gene expression levels for this gene in order to figure it out. I was trying the following seperate codes:

```
ggplot(habSolyc05g052120.2, aes(x = habSolyc05g052120.2[,1:6],
y = habSolyc05g052120.2[1,])) +
 geom_point()
```

```
ggplot(habSolyc05g052120.2) + 
geom_point(aes(x = (colnames(habSolyc05g052120.2)),
y = habSolyc05g052120.2[1,], 
fill = colnames(habSolyc05g052120.2)))
```

```
ggplot(habSolyc05g052120.2) +
geom_point(aes(x = (colnames(habSolyc05g052120.2)),
y = habSolyc05g052120.2[1,]))
```

```
ggplot(habSolyc05g052120.2[1,]) +
geom_point(aes(x = (colnames(habSolyc05g052120.2)),
y = habSolyc05g052120.2[1,], fill = colnames(habSolyc05g052120.2)))
```

None of them work, with each outputting some version of the Error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x and y
```

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.

Comment: Are you trying to use 6 columns from your `data.frame` for `x`?  And then for `y` you are only selecting the first row  in its entirty? Remember, one column per variable and one row per observation in your `data.frame`. Then you can have one variable for `x` and one for `y`.

Comment: Make  a long-form data frame.  There are several options but tidyr::pivot_longer() works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ggplot` for aesthetics, you should not index your dataframe, it gets all the variables by itself. 
I don't know your dataframe structure exactly because of bad format of your question, but may be it is what you want:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

# creating a dataframe similar to yours
habSolyc05g052129.2 <- data.frame(
  Shab_ovul1 = 0,
  Shab_poll1 = 0.6145496,
  Shab_poll2 = 0.368,
  Shab_styl1 = 0.043,
  Shab_styl2 = 0.0026,
  Shab_styl3 = 0.0405
)

# reshaping daraframe to ling format
habSolyc05g052129.2 <- habSolyc05g052129.2 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = 1:6, names_to = "Variables", values_to = "Values")

# main plot
ggplot(habSolyc05g052129.2, aes(x = Variables, y = Values)) +
  geom_point()
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, that did it perfectly. In the future how should I better present my data?

Comment: @tbiewerh, the usual format for SO is `dput` format. You can read its documentation and tutorial.